# I need create a variable that is the GMT offset where it's 7:XX AM right now

Tags: python, time, timezone

I've been working on this for a bit and not seeing the answer quite yet. Essentially, I need to add a conditional depending on a GMT offset into a script. The GMT offset needs to be wherever in the world it is 7 AM at the time the script runs.

In other words, if it's 7 AM in New York, I need to write a python script that will return '-4'.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: 
A script like this would work most of the time:

```
7 - time.gmtime().tm_hour
```

but when it's 11 PM (23) in GMT, the return is -15, and there isn't a GMT offset for -15 (only goes to -12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def OfsToHour(targetHour = 7):
    import datetime
    t = datetime.datetime.utcnow() #or your favored UTC call
    return (((targetHour - t.hour) + 12) % 24) - 12
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the > 12 thing the first time around!

Answer (score 1):

If it's 07:00 in New York, then it's 11:00 GMT.  7 - 11 = -4.

If it's 07:00 in Los Angeles, then it's 14:00 GMT.  7 - 14 = -7.

So take the current time in GMT, round it to the hour of your choice, and subtract from 7.

[update]

Ah, right, there is no -15...  But it all works mod 24.  So take `7-time.gmtime().tm_hour`, and if it is less than -12, add 24 to get the right answer.

[Sorry, but I do not actually know Python :-)]

Comment: Just posted a comment about this method in the updated question. Please take a look